# I am calling a url of the image from the webservice. The image is not loaded to uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsurlsession

During the debugging of the code I tested the URL, that url works in the browser and the image is displayed in the browser. But the below code is not loading the image to the image wrapper.

```
let row = indexPath.row
cell.NewsHeading.font =
UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
cell.NewsHeading.text = SLAFHeading[row]

if let url = NSURL(string: SLAFImages[indexPath.row]) {

     let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {  (data, response, error) -> Void in

     if error != nil {
         print("thers an error in the log")
     } else {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             cell.NewsImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

     }
    }

 }

 task.resume()    
}
 return cell
```

Comment: Does it throw an Exception or does it just not show up?

Comment: it doesnt throw an exception. It does not debug into  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url).. Its just skipping it.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint inside the callback (e.g. on line 'if error != nil'). That it's jumping over it is normal due to async behavior.

Comment: Ya. It debugged to the breakpoint inside the function. I am getting an error "NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550594

Comment: Looks like the server is giving back an error code (such as 404). You can get the `statusCode` property from the `response`. You might need to cast to `NSHTTPURLResponse` first.

Comment: dataTaskWithURL is asynchronous, and your `return cell` is *outside* the scope of the task. What happens in that you return the empty cell *before* the data has the time to be fetched in the background. You should not *return* from an async task but use callbacks ("completion handler"). Have a look at my profile there's many answers about this issue.

Comment: @EricD. Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm really sure the callback method of `dataTaskWithURL` has a reference to `cell` even after cell has been returned by the enclosing function. Just the image would show up as soon as the callback is done, not directly after cell return.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, you can't return from an asynchronous task - you can't know *when* the task will be complete and when the data will be available.

The way to handle this in Swift is to use callbacks, often called by convention "completion handlers".

In this example I create a function to run the network task, and this function has a callback for when the image is ready.

You call this function with a syntax named "trailing closure" and there you handle the result.

Here's an example for you.

The new function:

```
func getNewsImage(stringURL: String, completion: (image: UIImage)->()) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: stringURL) {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {  (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let data = data {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                        completion(image: image)
                    } else {
                        print("Error, data was not an image")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error, no data")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Your elements from your example:

```
let row = indexPath.row
cell.NewsHeading.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
cell.NewsHeading.text = SLAFHeading[row]
```

And how you call the new function:

```
getNewsImage(SLAFImages[indexPath.row]) { (image) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        cell.NewsImage.image = image
        // here you update your UI or reload your tableView, etc
    }
}
```

It's just an example to show how it works, so you might have to adapt to your app, but I believe it demonstrates what you need to do.

Comment: `dataTaskWithURL` has a callback method as parameter and the OP is using it. Also this callback is holding a reference to cell. So this answer is wrong in it's assumption (see question comments). Anyway it's still a working and good practice code. But it won't solve the OP's question.

Comment: `Also this callback is holding a reference to cell` Not anymore in my example. I often use this kind of structure and I believe it will solve OP's issue. If you have a better answer, be my guest, post it.

Comment: That's right. Your callback does not hold a reference, but the OP's did. Your code is just another design (cleaner), but it's doing the same thing except that you are also checking for `data`. But also this check won't show the image. I still think the problem lies on that the server is not giving back the correct response (see question comments).